# How to recover data from a formatted device [rooted, flashed]

Tags: rom-flashing, data-recovery, formatting

I've accidentally formatted my phone, via. `fastboot oem unlock`.

I've already tried [Wondershare](http://www.wondershare.com/), EaseUSMobile Saver.

Actually, I need my photos which has been shot by camera.

Till now I'm only able to fetch social photos.

PS - My phone is rooted & flashed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading and installing [Undelete App from the PlayStore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fahrbot.apps.undelete&referrer=utm_source%3DAndroidPIT%26utm_medium%3DAndroidPIT%26utm_campaign%3DAndroidPIT) and follow these simple steps:

1. Select the storage device from which you want to retrieve your data i.e. Internal or External.
2. Once selected scan the selected storage, the process will take 2-10min depending upon the memory size and data stored.
3. Once the scanning completes you will be presented with retrievable data in tabs: File, Pictures, Music, Videos etc.
4. Remember Recovered data returns to its origin, i.e wherever it was saved before they were lost.

PS: Always remember action fast over it's the key to get your deleted data back.

Comment: This cannot work after `fastboot oem unlock`; see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`fastboot oem unlock` is a secure wipe.  All data is completely destroyed and unrecoverable.  See [the official documentation](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/best-practices.html#unlockable-bootloaders):

> Unlockable Android devices must securely erase all user data prior to being unlocked.
>
> [...]
>
> To prevent the disclosure of user data, a device that supports unlocking needs to implement it properly.
>
> A properly implemented unlocking process will have the following properties:
>
> 1. When the unlocking command is confirmed by the user, the device MUST start an immediate data wipe. The "unlocked" flag MUST NOT be set until after the secure deletion is complete.
> 2. If a secure deletion cannot be completed, the device MUST stay in a locked state.
>
> [...]
>
> These requirements ensure that all data is destroyed upon the completion of an unlock operation.